# MS Access Form button that allows user to browse/choose file, then imports file to a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my database, I can made a command button import a file using the following:
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Raw Data from Import_ Import Specification", "Raw Data from Import", D:\Users\Denise_Griffith\Documents\Griffith\PRIME RECON FILES\jdaqawmslesfilesemailDLX_SHPREC_2017-04-26_03-33-47.csv, True, ""

But I would like to have the user choose the file to import, since the filename is different every day based on date and time it was created.  I have found this site (http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm) and was able to get the dialog to pop up to allow the user to navigate and select the file, but I do not know how to incorporate it so the file selected is imported using the specification I created, and into the appropriate table.

Please help!

Comment: Somewhere in your filedialog code, set a variable to the selected folder filepath and filename then reference that variable in your TransferText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a reference to **Microsoft Office Object Library**.

```
Public Sub ImportDocument()
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .InitialFileName = "Some folder"
        .Title = "Some Title"
        With .Filters
            .Clear
            .Add "CSV documents", "*.csv", 1
        End With
        .ButtonName = " Import Selected "
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show = 0 Then GoTo Leave
    End With

    Dim selectedItem As Variant
    For Each selectedItem In fd.SelectedItems
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Raw Data from Import_ Import Specification", "Raw Data from Import", selectedItem, True, ""
    Next

Leave:
    Set fd = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

**Update after user's comments:**

You must change the *Sub* to a *Function* and check the return value.

The simplest way is to return a `Boolean`, where `FALSE` indicates aborted and `TRUE` indicates success. However by doing so, you exclude the *Error* scenario as both Aborted and Error will return `FALSE`.

Therefore you can return a `Long` value e.g. 0, 1, 2 indicating Aborted, Success and Error respectively. In order to avoid the "magic numbers" though, I would create and return an *Enum* type as shown below:

```
Public Enum TaskImportEnum
    Aborted = 0 'default
    Success
    Failure
End Enum

Public Function ImportDocument() As TaskImportEnum
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .InitialFileName = "Some folder"
        .Title = "Dialog Title"
        With .Filters
            .Clear
            .Add "CSV documents", "*.csv", 1
        End With
        .ButtonName = " Import Selected "
        .AllowMultiSelect = False   'Change this to TRUE to enable multi-select

       'If aborted, the Function will return the default value of Aborted
        If .Show = 0 Then GoTo Leave
    End With

    Dim selectedItem As Variant
    For Each selectedItem In fd.SelectedItems
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Raw Data from Import_ Import Specification", "Raw Data from Import", selectedItem, True, ""
    Next selectedItem

   'Return Success
   ImportDocument = TaskImportEnum.Success

Leave:
    Set fd = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    ImportDocument = TaskImportEnum.Failure  'Return Failure if error
    Resume Leave
End Function
```

Lastly, you can call the Function like this:

```
Sub Import()

    Dim status_ As TaskImportEnum
        status_ = ImportDocument

    Select Case status_
        Case TaskImportEnum.Success:
            MsgBox "Success!"

        Case TaskImportEnum.Failure:
            MsgBox "Failure..."

        Case Else:
            MsgBox "Aborted..."
    End Select

End Sub
```

You can read more about the `Enum` type here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx

Comment: When I go to Tools.."References" is grayed out and I cannot get in to select anything.

Comment: I closed the VBA editor and re-opened and was able to select it.  This is working beautifully.  Thank you sooo much!

Comment: Is there any way to have a message box appear to say "action canceled" if the person clicks the cancel button in the dialog?  And conversely, the message box could say "file imported" when it is completed?

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will give this a try and see how it goes.

Comment: Works like a charm.  You are the bomb Kostas!