# MS Access Form button that allows user to browse/choose file excel , then imports file to a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my form access I want to make a button to browse / choose an excel file and import it in format a table in access.

This is my code.

' Requires reference to Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library. '

```
Public Function ImportDocument() As TaskImportEnum
On Error GoTo ErrProc

Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .InitialFileName = "Some folder"
    .Title = "Dialog Title"
    With .Filters
        .Clear
        .Add "xlsx documents", "*.xlsx", 1
    End With
    .ButtonName = " Import Selected "
    .AllowMultiSelect = False   'Change this to TRUE to enable multi-select

   'If aborted, the Function will return the default value of Aborted
    If .Show = 0 Then GoTo Leave
End With

Dim selectedItem As Variant
For Each selectedItem In fd.SelectedItems
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Raw Data from Import_ Import Specification", "Raw Data from Import", selectedItem, True, ""
Next selectedItem

ImportDocument = TaskImportEnum.Success

Leave:
Set fd = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function

ErrProc:
MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical
ImportDocument = TaskImportEnum.Failure  'Return Failure if error
Resume Leave
End Function
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem / the question?

Comment: The problem is that when selecting the excel file it does not want to import, please if you have the solution help me

Comment: *it does not want to import* sigh. Please read [ask] and edit your question accordingly. As it stands, it will probably get closed.

Comment: What happens - error message, wrong results, nothing?

Comment: The problem is I do not know how to recover the path from file Dialog vba, because normally it needed another code to link the path selected with file dialog, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in question is part of a solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744977/ms-access-form-button-that-allows-user-to-browse-choose-file-then-imports-file/43746113#43746113). However, a few changes are required as the solution provided relates to a CSV file import.

---

In a Standard Module, paste the following:

```
Public Enum TaskImportEnum
    Aborted = 0 'default
    Success
    Failure
End Enum

Public Function ImportDocument() As TaskImportEnum
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .InitialFileName = "Some folder"
        .Title = "Dialog Title"
        With .Filters
            .Clear
            .Add "Excel documents", "*.xlsx", 1
        End With
        .ButtonName = " Import Selected "
        .AllowMultiSelect = False   'Change this to TRUE to enable multi-select

       'If aborted, the Function will return the default value of Aborted
        If .Show = 0 Then GoTo Leave
    End With

    Dim selectedItem As Variant
    For Each selectedItem In fd.SelectedItems
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "YourTableName", selectedItem, True, "YourSheetName$" 'Change 'YourTableName' and 'YourSheetName' to the actual names
    Next selectedItem

   'Return Success
   ImportDocument = TaskImportEnum.Success

Leave:
    Set fd = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    ImportDocument = TaskImportEnum.Failure  'Return Failure if error
    Resume Leave
End Function
```

---

On your button's Click event paste the following:

```
Dim status_ As TaskImportEnum
    status_ = ImportDocument

Select Case status_
    Case TaskImportEnum.Success:
        MsgBox "Success!"

    Case TaskImportEnum.Failure:
        MsgBox "Failure..."

    Case Else:
        MsgBox "Aborted..."
End Select
```

Comment: I want to import the excel file into a table already existing in the access database.this is my code,I need your held thank you.

Comment: The above should work. Just change 'YourTableName' and 'YourSheetName' to the actual names. What is the error?

Comment: Yes you are right, just me I want to import this file into a table that already exists in the database access. please